# Maze-Jigsaw Fusion

Tags: cipher, mazes, jigsaw-puzzle

---

Hello there, maze lovers! Tired of solving normal mazes? Here is a maze puzzle with a little twist: a jigsaw-maze!

The circular maze has been divided into four quadrants and scattered, so that you have to reassemble them first. Once you have correctly set up the maze, you will be able to go from the opening on the outer wall to the middle circle.

[image: Full maze]

Here is each piece in separate images: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk3NM.png), [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aolUJ.png), [(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKXyS.png), [(4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkMLE.png)

That's it!

Wait... Have I forgotten something? I hope not.

Anyway, enjoy the challenge :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Here are the four quadrants let’s call them quadrants 1,2,3,4 left to right.

> [image]

A possible line of thinking to complete the jigsaw:

Firstly

> Using the cipher tag and seeing the layout of the dots, I assumed that the cipher being used is the [Morse code cipher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code). I saw that quadrant 1 contained the entrance so I needed to start there whatever the actual configuration is. With a little bit of experimentation I saw that, with the white dots being dots and the black dots being dashes, going along the only path of the maze that I can move through the word **HINT** being spelt out. So the way forward seemed to be a finding a coherent message that the path to the center of the maze will reveal and it will be done so by translating the dots using this cipher…

> [image]

> Continuing on this train of thought I could see that there were two options I could go with to complete the maze. But if the maze wanted me to continue in the same direction then quadrant 2 being the NE quadrant is the only possible option as the other two quadrants lead to dead ends as shown by the red lines:

> [image]

> But if I assume this quadrant as the solution then it leads to somewhat unconvincing results in 3 out of 4 possible solution paths if one were to translate the string of dots into letters. So I deduced that whatever the actual configuration is, I needed to go with the ‘second option’ to complete the maze.

> [image]

> For example green led to:

> [image]

> Upon choosing this option there are three further options that are then presented to be the possible paths but the blue and green lead to unconvincing results when I translated the code I crossed over so I had to go with with the red.

> [image]

> For example the green led to:

> [image]

> Going down the red path then spelt I saw quite conveniently **HINT FOR A** … Also I could, following from this, see that quadrant 3 and quadrant 2 cannot be the SW quadrant. Since they will both lead to dead ends. So I deduced that quadrant 4 is the SW quadrant.

> [image]

> [image]

> Before I proceeded any further, I checked the message running across the only path to solve the maze based on my assumptions to see if I am on the right track and translating what is highlighted in red the results were convincing as I got: **HINT FOR A HIDDEN PU(ZZ)** which made me certain I was going on the right track.

> Finding the positions of the positions of the next two quadrants was trivial: Having quadrant 3 for the SE quadrant lead to an unsolvable maze. Therefore quadrant 3 is the NE quadrant and quadrant 2 is the SE quadrant and I should have completed the maze.

> [image]

> [image]

> It turned out that my assumptions all along were correct since the maze I ended up with is solvable.

I then solved the maze like so:

> [image]

Next

> Using the Morse code cipher that I have assumed to be the cipher, I translated rest of the code I crossed over where the whites dots are dots and the black dots are dashes revealing:

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> HINT FOR A HIDDEN PUZZLE REMOVE ONE SLICE WRAP THE REST INTO A CONE ANOTHER MAZE!

> Following this hint and removing the SE slice since this is the only slice we can take away to make a solvable maze, I could then complete another (albeit conical) maze hence completing the puzzle.

> (The center highlighted in red in the top image shows that this cone will lead to a closed center):

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

CodeWarrior0 has also found some nice Easter eggs:

> https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/125664/6227

Comment: Good job! This is correct. The last character in the hint (#) also should be a valid character. Just curious, on which attempt did you get the correct configuration? Seems to be easier than I planned :P

Comment: No, it's a punctuation mark.

Comment: Don’t worry found it 

Comment: I honestly can’t remember OP but not to many attempts I have a good ability to visualize probably because I spend a lot of time daydreaming!

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify how you got the first picture?

Comment: (And what does the cone read?)

Comment: @msh the cone doesn’t read anything… the final answer is the completed maze… cone maze

Comment: @msh sure I will show you how to get both mazes give me a second even though I am probably going to get 0 reward for it.

Comment: @ msh is this what you were asking for?

Answer (score 5):

I can continue from PDT's solved maze, and find...

> More Morse-encoded words. "For Bonus Puzzle", "Wrong way", "Morse co[...]", "The correct path", "lies", "to", but there are also a handful of nonsense letters. I can't tell if I'm looking at another puzzle piece or just an easter egg!
>  [image]

Comment: Yeah, I added some easter eggs too, just for fun :) The correct answer is already given.

Answer (score 2):

The drawing was tougher than finding the path.
Should be alright according to me

> [image]

> [image]

Also can someone tell any better way to draw the path, this is as good as I could with paint.

Comment: Faster than expected. Btw, there's more to it :). Check the tags.

Comment: @ACB Interesting, but how exactly do I wrap it into a cone, I cannot think of any suitable way, even if I removed one of the slices